# No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome

Tags: android, selenium, appium, selenium-chromedriver, emulation

Background tested:

Android 7.0, 8.0, 8.1

Appium 1.8.1

ChromeDriver version tested:

2.17, 2.23, 2.30, 2.34

As I were using Android Emulator to use Chrome that's already in the system, I kept getting the same error, which is "No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome 51.0.2704". I've tested both lower and higher version of the driver, and switched from Android 7.0 to 8.0, 8.1, I was still receiving the same error.

```
import unittest, os
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class test(unittest,TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        capabilities.setCapability("broserName", 'Android');
        capabilities.setCapability("version", '7.0');
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", 'Android Emulator');
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", 'Browser');
        driver = webdriver.Remote("https://localhost:4723/wd/hub", capabilities)
        driver.get('https://www.google.com')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsfromTestCase(test)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity = 2).run(suite)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/

Download the chromedriver from the above link and point the downloaded path in the code.

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable","C:\\AutomationProject\\node_modules\\appium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just point out the Chrome driver path when starting the Appium server.